# k3d: local repository not found

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, k3s

I've created my loca registry:

```
$ docker container run -d 
  --name registry.localhost
  --restart always
  -p 5000:5000
  registry:2
```

It's up and running:

```
$ curl -s registry.localhost:5000/v2/_catalog | jq
{
  "repositories": [
   "greenplum-for-kubernetes",
   "greenplum-operator"
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to create a deployment. However I'm getting:

```
4m7s        Normal    ScalingReplicaSet         deployment/greenplum-operator              Scaled up replica set greenplum-operator-76b544fbb9 to 1
4m7s        Normal    SuccessfulCreate          replicaset/greenplum-operator-76b544fbb9   Created pod: greenplum-operator-76b544fbb9-pm7t2
<unknown>   Normal    Scheduled                 pod/greenplum-operator-76b544fbb9-pm7t2    Successfully assigned default/greenplum-operator-76b544fbb9-pm7t2 to k3d-k3s-default-agent-0
3m23s       Normal    Pulling                   pod/greenplum-operator-76b544fbb9-pm7t2    Pulling image "registry.localhost:5000/greenplum-operator:v2.2.0"
3m23s       Warning   Failed                    pod/greenplum-operator-76b544fbb9-pm7t2    Error: ErrImagePull
3m23s       Warning   Failed                    pod/greenplum-operator-76b544fbb9-pm7t2    Failed to pull image "registry.localhost:5000/greenplum-operator:v2.2.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "registry.localhost:5000/greenplum-operator:v2.2.0": failed to resolve reference "registry.localhost:5000/greenplum-operator:v2.2.0": failed to do request: Head https://registry.localhost:5000/v2/greenplum-operator/manifests/v2.2.0: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
3m1s        Warning   Failed                    pod/greenplum-operator-76b544fbb9-pm7t2    Error: ImagePullBackOff
3m1s        Normal    BackOff                   pod/greenplum-operator-76b544fbb9-pm7t2    Back-off pulling image "registry.localhost:5000/greenplum-operator:v2.2.0"
```

In short:

> http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

My cluster is up and running as well:

```
$ k3d cluster create --agents 2 --k3s-server-arg --disable=traefik
  --volume $HOME/.k3d/registries.yaml:/etc/rancher/k3s/my-registries.yaml
```

As you can see:

```
$ cat ${HOME}/.k3d/registries.yaml
mirrors:
  "registry.localhost:5000":
    endpoint:
      - "http://registry.localhost:5000"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related with `k3s` and I mage a miswriting.

`k3s` needs to get access to `/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml` file, as you can see [here](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/private-registry/).

The problem is push a `my-registries.yaml` file instead of `registries.yaml`:

```
$ k3d cluster create --agents 2 --k3s-server-arg --disable=traefik
  --volume $HOME/.k3d/registries.yaml:/etc/rancher/k3s/my-registries.yaml
```

The problem was solved:

```
$ k3d cluster create --agents 2 --k3s-server-arg --disable=traefik
  --volume $HOME/.k3d/registries.yaml:/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this your workers

Create or modify /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{ "insecure-registries":["registry.localhost:5000"] }
```

Restart docker daemon

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Source: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1874